# hasManyThrough eloquent issue

Tags: laravel, has-many-through

I have faced with a problem with joining the tables with hasMany way

The tables I have:

brands:{ id - integer; name - string; image- string; }

products:{ id - integer; brand_id - integer; name - string ; }

clients:{ id - integer; name - string; surname - string; tel - string; }

orders:{ id - integer; client_id - integer; product_id - integer; }

In brands model:

```
public function clients(){

return $this->hasManyThrough(
    clients::class,
    orders::class,
    products::class,
    'brand_id',
    'product_id',
    'client_id',
    'id',
    'id',
    'id');
}
```

in clients model:

```
public function brands(){

return $this->hasManyThrough(
    brands::class,
    products::class,
    orders::class,
    'client_id',
    'product_id',
    'brand_id',
    'id',
    'id',
    'id');
}
```

My query on ordersController is like:

```
public function list(){

    return view('orders',[
        'data' => brands::orderbyDesc('id')->with('products')->with('orders')->with('clients')->where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->get()
    ]);
```

I get the below error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'orders.App\Models\products' in 'field list'

How can I connect the "clients" table with the "brands" table?

The final destination route is orders, so i get the name and surname of client, name of the brand, name of the product and other product attributes

Would be grateful if you tell me where my logic is failing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hasManyThrough to declare relations that go further than 2 levels deep. You can read more in the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) and [the api](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasManyThrough.html). There is a package that you can use for more deep relationships called [Eloquent HasManyDeep](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep). You can take a look [here](https://laravel-news.com/hasmanydeep-package) for an example.

Comment: Is it still actual for laravel 9? Haven't seen "hasmanyDeep" on the documentation

Comment: The hasManyDeep is an external package you can find in the link provided above. If you see the hasManyThrough function in the laravel 9 api you will see that you have provided wrong parameters and that is the reason you get the error message in the database query.